# Remove rows with NA in the calculation but have them remain in the dataset using R

Tags: r, dplyr, null, na

I have a dataset that contains two columns and combines them to create one extra column.

```
df$date_time<-paste(df$date, format(as.POSIXct(df$`time), '%T'))
```

However some rows don't contain information so they are NA's. When i run the calculation it includes the na rows and assigns them a character and so my column becomes a character.

How can i do a the script  that runs the calculation but excludes the rows that contain na?

For example I tried to do this with dplyr

```
df$date_time<-paste(df$date, format(as.POSIXct(df$time), '%T') %>%
                                    filter(STOP_DATA$`Stop Frisk Date`!= is.na()))
```

All I want is the same calculation but to exclude rows with na so that my result remains a POSIXct and does not turn into character because the rows with NA were included in the calc.

Comment: I don't think you need to remove NA because many packages will correctly ignore NA. What is the "calculation" you are performing?

Comment: so i have it written above. Its not a calculation as much as it is two columns combining into one. However there is a row that has na's when those columns combined the result is "NA" as a character. So the whole column becomes a character.

Comment: Could you put some data in a usable way? Also, what do you expect as result when hours are NA?

Comment: So i have date and time separate columns. When I paste they combine. Some Rows are NA so instead of ignoring those rows there becomes a character paste "NA NA" hence the column becomes Character and not Posixct as it was before. I want the paste to ignore the NA's and leave them as NA's in the paste.

Comment: Can you add a small example of your data and show expected output based on that.  Read about how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Base R and Lubridate possible answers

Example data:

```
foo <- tibble(
    x = c("2020-01-01", NA, "2020-01-07"),
    y = c("09:00", NA, NA)
    )
```

try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

foo %>% 
    mutate(solution1 = as.POSIXct(paste(x,ifelse(is.na(y),"00:00",y)), 
                                  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
           solution2 = ymd_hm(paste(x,ifelse(is.na(y),"00:00",y))))
```

output:

```
 x          y     solution1           solution2          
  <chr>      <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2020-01-01 09:00 2020-01-01 09:00:00 2020-01-01 09:00:00
2 NA         NA    NA                  NA                 
3 2020-01-07 NA    2020-01-07 00:00:00 2020-01-07 00:00:00
>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```r
df$date_time <- ifelse(is.na(df2$date_time), "", paste(...))
```

replace `...` with the operation you want.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I plugged in this df$date, format(as.POSIXct(df$`time), '%T')

Comment: do you notice that you put an extra backtick before time?